# Access non-public members - ReflectionAttribute

Tags: c#, .net, security

I am loading assembly B from assembly A. I am trying to enumerate private members of the type located in assembly B.

How do I use ReflectionPermission to accomplish this task? I couldn't find anything useful on the MSDN.

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("Chapter13.exe", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence);
//AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("Chapter13");

Type t = asm.GetType("Chapter13.ProtectedBuffer");

MemberInfo[] members = t.GetMembers(BindingFlags.NonPublic);

foreach (MemberInfo m in members)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Name);
}
```

Kind regards
PK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're running in a partial-trust environment, you don't need `ReflectionPermission`. I suspect your problem is that you're not specifying static/instance. Try this:

```
MemberInfo[] members = t.GetMembers(BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                                    BindingFlags.Static |
                                    BindingFlags.Instance);
```