# In a combobox, how do I determine the highlighted item (not selected item)?

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

First, fair warning: I am a complete newbie with C# and WPF.

I have a combobox (editable, searchable) and I would like to be able to intercept the Delete key and remove the currently highlighted item from the list. The behavior I'm looking for is like that of MS Outlook when entering in email addresses. When you give a few characters, a dropdown list of potential matches is displayed. If you move to one of these (with the arrow keys) and hit Delete, that entry is permanently removed. I want to do that with an entry in the combobox.

Here is the XAML (simplified):

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Directory"
    KeyUp="Directory_KeyUp"
    IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
    IsEditable="True"
    Text="{Binding Path=CurrentDirectory, Mode=TwoWay}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static self:Properties.Settings.Default}, 
        Path=DirectoryList, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

The handler is:

```
private void Directory_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox box = sender as ComboBox;
    if (box.IsDropDownOpen &&  (e.Key == Key.Delete))
    {
        TrimCombobox("DirectoryList", box.HighlightedItem);  // won't compile!
    }
}
```

When using the debugger, I can see `box.HighlightedItem` has the value I want but when I try and put in that code, it fails to compile with:

`System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox' does not contain a definition for 'HighlightedItem'...`

So: how do I access that value? Keep in mind that the item has **not** been selected. It is merely highlighted as the mouse hovers over it.

Thanks for your help.

Here is a screenshot showing the debugger's display. I hovered over "box" and when the one-line summary was displayed, I then hovered over the + char to expand to this image:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/2cff35d340.gif](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/2cff35d340.gif)

Comment: What exactly to do you mean when you say you can see box.HighlightedItem in the debugger? Is it in a watch window? There is no public HighlightedItem property in ComboBox.

Comment: I added a picture to the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Highlighted Item property is a Non-Public member, so you can't call it from another class.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/1e4dc53cee.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/1e4dc53cee.png)

I believe you need to use Reflection to get at Non-Public members. Here's a SO post on the subject: [Access non-public members - ReflectionAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769634/access-non-public-members-reflectionattribute)

Comment: That seems to have done it. Thanks! I will put the final code in a separate answer but credit you with the "winner."

Comment: Jean, how do you get the Watch window to separate out "Non-Public members"? I've tried this in VS2008 and VS2010 (Pro edition) and it doesn't do that. If it had, I might have figure out the problem much sooner.

Comment: I mouse over the item I want to see, then go to Raw View, then base, then Non Public Members is usually shown. Sometimes there are multiple levels of (base) if you are using inheritance.

I am using VS 2010 Ultimate (Still using free RC while it lasts ;)), but I think it should be in Pro.

Comment: No Raw View for me. Must be for Ultimate and I ain't got $11K to spend on it! Thanks, anyway.

Comment: FYI I think you can still get the RC for free, but it will expire in the coming months.
Personally, I'd ask a question to SO whether Raw View is only available in 2010 Ultimate. With the thousands of SO users using multiple versions of Visual Studio, you should get an answer. Also, check your Debug Settings.

Comment: I tried a new solution with Visual Studio 2008 Pro Edition, I was able to see the Non-Public members of a form by hovering the mouse over "this", and then clicking on base. Non Public Members was at the bottom of the list.

So I guess Raw View might be something VS/WPF related. I don't think it's an Ultimate only thing, though.

Comment: On rare occasions, I see a Raw View, but it is often empty. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7):

Below is the final code, as inspired by Jean Azzopardi's answer. The `HighlightedItem` that was showing up in the debugger was a non-public property and I am forcing access with a sequence of `GetType().GetProperty().GetValue()`

```
private void Directory_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox box = sender as ComboBox;
    if (box.IsDropDownOpen && (e.Key == Key.Delete))
    {
        const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance;
        PropertyInfo hl = box.GetType().GetProperty("HighlightedItem", flags);
        if (hl != null)
        {
            String hlString = hl.GetValue(sender, null) as String;
            // TODO: remove from DirectoryList
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem and your solution solved it, but it didn't work out-of-the-box. I had to look at some information in the debugger to find that the "HighlightedItem" property was named "HighlightedElement" in my version (.NET 4.0), so I changed that string in the GetProperty() call. The rest works flawlessly. Thanks!

Comment: I too had to use the `HighlightedElement` property, but had another problem in that I needed the databound item. I was able to store the value returned from `GetValue()` as a `ComboBoxItem` and then use the `Content` property within that to get the actual item that the `HighlightedElement` was bound to.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own DrawItem Event handler and save the index of the items as they are actively being drawn and keep the DrawItemState.Selected (ie. the highlighted) one.

```
void Main()
{
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ComboBox ComboBox1;
    string[] ds = new string[]{"Foo", "Bar", "Baz"};

    public Form1 ()
    {
        InitializeComboBox();
    }

    private void InitializeComboBox()
    {
        ComboBox1 = new ComboBox();

        ComboBox1.DataSource = ds;
        Controls.Add(ComboBox1);

        ComboBox1.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
        ComboBox1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(ComboBox1_DrawItem);
    }

    private void ComboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        e.Graphics.DrawString(ds[e.Index],ComboBox1.Font,Brushes.Black,e.Bounds);

        if (e.State == DrawItemState.Selected)
        {
            //stores the "HighlightedIndex" in the control's tag field.  Change as you see fit.
            ComboBox1.Tag = e.Index; 
            //Console.WriteLine(e.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I'm not using Forms but rather WPF 3.5

Answer (score -1):

The definition of [System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox_members(v=VS.85).aspx) does not contain a property `HighlightedItem` - that's why you're code does not compile.

Are you using a combo box derived from System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox? Then just cast it to the appropriate type.

**Later note:** 
If you want to catch the highlighted event of a ComboBox read [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/e234c4a7-0cf7-4284-a072-8152f7593002) link - it addresses exactly this issue.

Comment: What would that type be? And why does the debugger show HighlightedItem?

Comment: Don't know what you are looking at in the debugger - can you copy/paste what variable you are watching and what type you get for that variable?

Comment: Picture added to the original post. This is what I am looking for.

Comment: One solution to your issue is to catch the highlight event - I edited my post, see the link there for more information

Comment: Alas, that seems to be for Windows.Forms rather than WPF. Thanks anyway