# Removing selected items (highlighted) from DropDown

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I'm wondering is it possible to remove highlighted items with `Key.Delete`, while a `DropDown` is Open?

[image: example]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/eolrdqjq.mx3.png))</sub>

What I've tried..

**C#**

```
    private void OnKeyUpHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Boolean delete = e.Key == Key.Delete;
        if (sender == cbkSnpCodes && (delete && cbkSnpCodes.IsDropDownOpen))
        {
            cbkSnpCodes.Items.Remove(cbkSnpCodes.SelectedItem);
            cbkSnpCodes.Items.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SnpCodeModel}" Name="cbkSnpCodes" Controls:TextboxHelper.Watermark="Enter an snp code and press enter" MaxDropDownHeight="50" KeyUp="OnKeyUpHandler" KeyDown="OnKeyDownHandler" DisplayMemberPath="SnpCode" IsEditable="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding Path=SnpCode, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="False" Height="26" Margin="81,9,0,0" Width="223" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
```

**Binding Class `SnpCodeModel`**

```
class SnpCodeModel
{
    public string SnpCode { get; set; }

    public SnpCodeModel(string _snpcode)
    {
            this.SnpCode = _snpcode;
    }
}
```

I have also tried the solution posted by [Harold Bamford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10574/harold-bamford) on the Stackoverflow question: 
[In a combobox, how do I determine the highlighted item (not selected item)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723977/in-a-combobox-how-do-i-determine-the-highlighted-item-not-selected-item)

```
    private void OnKeyUpHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Boolean delete = e.Key == Key.Delete;
        ComboBox box = sender as ComboBox;
        if (box.IsDropDownOpen && delete)
        {
            const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance;
            PropertyInfo hl = box.GetType().GetProperty("HighlightedItem", flags);
            if (hl != null)
            {
                String hlString = hl.GetValue(sender, null).ToString();
                SnpCodeModel snp = new SnpCodeModel(hlString);
                cbkSnpCodes.Items.Remove(snp);
                cbkSnpCodes.Items.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work :-( and produces this output within the `System.Diagnostics;`

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=VerticalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'ComboBoxItem' (Name=''); target property is 'VerticalContentAlignment' (type 'VerticalAlignment')
```

The main problem with my current attempts is that because the `ComboBox` is editable the item that I am trying to Delete becomes `null` before it reaches `cbkSnpCodes.Items.Remove`.

Is it possible to achieve the functionality I'm looking for? I haven't been able to find much on google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of SnpCodeModel with `SnpCodeModel snp = new SnpCodeModel(hlString);`. Even though it has the same content, it cant be found in cbkSnpCodes, because its not the same instance as the HighlightedItem.

Try something like

```
        if (hl != null)
        {
            box.Items.Remove(hl.GetValue(sender, null));
            //box.Items.Refresh();
        }
```

or override the Equals method in your SnpCodeModel:

```
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is SnpCodeModel)
            return ((SnpCodeModel)obj).SnpCode == this.SnpCode

        return false;
    }
```